# Bash conditional pipe to select statement

Tags: bash, loops

I want to have a conditional pipe to a select loop, I have found several answers on conditional pipes but haven't been able to get any to work. Is something like this possible?

```
if [ $condition -eq 0 ]; then
    select action in "${actions[@]}"; do
elif [ $condition -eq 1 ]; then
    sleep 0.1 | yes 1 | select action in "${actions[@]}"; do
fi
        [[ ! "$REPLY" =~ $isNum ]] && continue
        # Edit because someone is getting upset
        #"${action[@]}"
    done
```

This give the error `syntax error near unexpected token elif`

Comment: What's the point of piping from `sleep 0.1`? The `sleep` happens at the same time as the copy of `yes`, which happens at the same time as the `select`. Because they're all happening at the same time, the `sleep` doesn't actually _do anything_; `yes` doesn't need to wait for the sleep to finish before it starts.

Comment: Also, bash arrays are arrays _of strings_, not arrays _of arrays_, so `"${action[@]}"` quite certainly doesn't do what you want it to; `action` is just a string, not an array.

Comment: `"${action[@]}"` does exactly what I want it to do

Comment: More precisely, then: It doesn't do anything different from what just `"$action"` would do, so if you're using it as `"${action[@]}"`, you're _implying_ you want something different that isn't actually available.

Comment: I wrote the sleep/ yes part a while ago but if iirc I was getting errors without the sleep and found an answer that said to use sleep and it worked

Comment: Action is an array when I use it I just trimmed the code and none of this has anything to do with the question.

Comment: If you trim your code _into something that doesn't work as given in the question_, it's not a [mre], and is thus off-topic. `select action in` makes `action` be a string, not an array.

Comment: Only the part relevant to the question has to work. If you want to grade all my code I can send it to you, otherwise stick to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Block statements need to be nested properly, you can't use a conditional around just the statement that starts a block.

If you want to avoid writing the `select` block twice, put it in a function.

```
do_select() {
    select action in "${actions[@]}"; do
        [[ ! "$REPLY" =~ $isNum ]] && continue
        "${action[@]}"
    done
}

if [ $condition -eq 0 ]; then
    do_select
else
    sleep 0.1 | yes 1 | do_select
fi
```